# Racket: sliding window over a vector

Tags: scheme, racket, sliding-window, subsequence

What are some good ways to perform a sliding window over a finite sequence in Racket, such as finding the highest sum of any sub-sequence of 4 numbers?

```
(define example #(3 1 4 5 10 23 1 50 0 12 40 12 43 20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find prefix sums:

```
#lang racket
(define example #(3 1 4 5 10 23 1 50 0 12 40 12 43 20))

(define-values (sums sum)
  (for/fold ([sums '()] [sum 0]) ([x example])
    (values (cons sum sums) (+ sum x))))
(list->vector (cons sum sums))
```

Result:

```
'#(224 204 161 149 109 97 97 47 46 23 13 8 4 3 0)
```

Then ... profit.

Where profit could be this:

```
#lang racket
(define example #(3 1 4 5 10 23 1 50 0 12 40 12 43 20))

(define (prefix-sums xs)
  (define-values (sums sum)
    (for/fold ([sums '()] [sum 0]) ([x xs])
      (values (cons sum sums) (+ sum x))))
  (list->vector (reverse (cons sum sums))))

(define (sum4 xs i)
  (- (vector-ref xs (+ i 4))
     (vector-ref xs    i)))

(define (sum4s xs)
  (for/list ([i (- (vector-length xs) 4)])
    (sum4 (prefix-sums xs) i)))

(apply max (sum4s example))
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic approach, here's a sequence constructor that returns a sliding window of `len` elements from a vector, `len` values at a time, which can then be used with `for` comprehensions:

```lisp
(define (in-vector-window v len)
  (make-do-sequence
   (lambda ()
     (values
      (lambda (i) (vector->values v i (+ i len)))
      add1
      0
      (lambda (i) (<= (+ i len) (vector-length v)))
      #f
      #f))))
```

And some example usages:

```lisp
> (for/list ([(a b c d) (in-vector-window example 4)]) (list a b c d))
'((3 1 4 5) (1 4 5 10) (4 5 10 23) (5 10 23 1) (10 23 1 50) (23 1 50 0) (1 50 0 12) (50 0 12 40) (0 12 40 12) (12 40 12 43) (40 12 43 20))
> (define sums (for/list ([(a b c d) (in-vector-window example 4)]) (+ a b c d)))
> (foldl max (car sums) (cdr sums))
115
```

Comment: Old but interesting question without a general-purpose answer.